# CountUp Javascript Package and self.d is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Any ideas on why I would be getting the following error with the countUp Javascript package.

> TypeError: self.d is null

```
<script>
    var numPendingOrders = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/admin/orders/getPendingOrders",
    });

    var options = {
        useEasing : true,
        useGrouping : true,
        separator : ',',
        decimal : '.',
        prefix : '',
        suffix : ''
    };
    var users = new CountUp("numPendingOrders", 0, numPendingOrders, 0, 5, options);
    users.start();
</script>
```

Comment: Probably because `numPendingOrders` contains the jqXHR object returned by `$.ajax` not the data.

Comment: Yup, need to look at the resolved promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign the

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/admin/orders/getPendingOrders",
    });
```

to your `numPendingOrders` which is not the result of the `ajax` call.Instead do like

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/admin/orders/getPendingOrders",
        success: function(data){
          var options = {
            useEasing : true,
            useGrouping : true,
            separator : ',',
            decimal : '.',
            prefix : '',
            suffix : ''
          };

           var users = new CountUp("numPendingOrders", 0, data, 0, 5, options);
           users.start();
        }
    });
```